# SQL query with percentage calculation from subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery, aggregate-functions

I have one table: **log**

```
+----+---------------------+---------------+
| ID |        Time         |    Status     |
+----+---------------------+---------------+
|  1 | 2016-07-19 03:20:12 | 200 OK        |
|  2 | 2016-07-20 05:20:12 | 404 NOT FOUND |
|  3 | 2016-07-19 00:00:00 | 200 OK        |
|  4 | 2016-07-20 10:20:12 | 404 NOT FOUND |
|  5 | 2016-08-05 07:00:02 | 404 NOT FOUND |
+----+---------------------+---------------+
```

I need to consolidate the data by "404 NOT FOUND" status group by date order by percentage of total. (bellow)

**Desirable outcome**

```
+---------------------+---------+
|        Date         | Errors  |
+---------------------+---------+
| 2016-07-20 00:00:00 | 0.66666 |
| 2016-08-05 00:00:00 | 0.33333 |
+---------------------+---------+
```

I can't figure out how can I achieve that from just one query. By the time, I started with this query:

```
SELECT date_trunc('day',time) as "date", count(time) as errors
FROM log
WHERE status = '404 NOT FOUND'
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY errors DESC;
```

This query result in:

```
+---------------------+--------+
|        Date         | Errors |
+---------------------+--------+
| 2016-07-20 00:00:00 |      2 |
| 2016-08-05 00:00:00 |      1 |
+---------------------+--------+
```

Anny ideas or references to achieve the desirable outcome?

Answer (score 3):

To get your desired output, try this query :

```
SELECT date_trunc('day',time) as "date", round((
  count(*)::decimal/(
            select count(*) from log WHERE status = '404 NOT FOUND')
),2) as errors
FROM log
WHERE status = '404 NOT FOUND'
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY errors DESC;
```

This will display :

```
date                       errors
2016-07-20T00:00:00.000Z    0.67
2016-08-05T00:00:00.000Z    0.33
```

This is a working [**Fiddle**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pzz53rhjLo9YCgYjwVpLDU/1)

*Don't worry about the date format, in my schema I chose a `timestamp` type*

Answer (score 1):

I think window functions are the most elegant answer:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   EXTRACT(day FROM time) AS date,
   CAST(
      count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY CAST(time AS date))
      AS double precision
   ) / count(*) OVER () as errors
FROM log                                                                            
WHERE status = '404 NOT FOUND'
ORDER BY errors DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this Answer.

Hope this helps you:

```
SELECT date_trunc('day',time) as "date"
    ,COUNT(time)/(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM log WHERE status = '404 NOT FOUND') as errors
FROM log
WHERE status = '404 NOT FOUND'
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY errors DESC;
```

Comment: Integer division truncates.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will be helpful. I used postgresql9.3

```
select * 
from (
  with total as (select sum(1) as tot FROM log WHERE status = '404 NOT FOUND')
  SELECT date_trunc('day',time) as "date",
  cast(SUM(CASE WHEN status = '404 NOT FOUND' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as decimal) / total.tot as percentage
  FROM log , total
  group by date, total.tot
    ) t
where percentage > 0
ORDER BY percentage desc;
```

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you try with this:

```
select 
  date_trunc('day',time) as "date", 
  count(time)/(select count(*) from log where status='404 NOT FOUND') as errors
from log
where status = '404 NOT FOUND'
GROUP BY date_trunc('day',time);
```

Comment: The count(*) returns the number of rows in a table satisfying the criteria specified in the WHERE clause, so the result of count(time)/count(*) will be always 1.0

Comment: You are right, I have made a little change on the query, check that out. Maybe you can save the initial count into a variable to make the query easier to read

Comment: @user1301037: that's not entirely true - `count(time)` will only count rows where time is not null. http://rextester.com/NGPG77727 But in this case those two are the same, yes.

Comment: Integer division truncates.